# TypeScript struggling with simple type inference for string literal

Tags: typescript, type-inference

I ran into a problem with type inference, and tried to create the smallest reproducible example possible

```
type Options = { value: 'a' | 'b' }

const getOption = (): Options => {
    const result = { value: 'a' };
    return result;
}
```

#### Error

> Type '{ value: string; }' is not assignable to type 'Options'.
>
> __ Types of property 'value' are incompatible.
>
> ____   Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"a" | "b"'

---

*(I'm **not** asking for a solution. I want to know why why TypeScript can't infer this)*

I can return the result in a single operation without the error. I assume TypeScript is inferring the `result` variable to be of the type `{ value: string }` instead of `{ value: 'a' }`

To fix it I can change the result line to cast the string value to the literal it actually is, but it seems beyond silly.....

```
const result = { value: ('a' as 'a') };
```

#### Question

How come this is necessary? I'm usually always impressed about the depth of TypeScript's type inference, but for some reason it is struggling with this simple problem

Comment: Well, `return { value: 'a' }` works fine: [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=4&ssc=5&pln=4&pc=27#code/C4TwDgpgBA8mwEsD2A7AzlAvFA3lAbgIYA2ArhAFxQDkh1UAPjQEb0C+AUBwMaprBQA5hGBxEqLFAAUASipjk6LAD5cHKBqgAnEaS0pcBEuSq12Abg5sgA) I guess the check through reference for object not being changed is expensive for the TS compiler, hence it's not performed. You can also say `const result = { value: 'a' } as const;` or `const result: Options = { value: 'a' };` but seems a bit redundant.

Comment: You can add the type the `result` variable like this: `const result: Options = { value: 'a' };`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use an `as const` assertion instead:

```js
type Options = { value: 'a' | 'b' }

const getOption = (): Options => {
    const result = { value: 'a' } as const;
    return result;
}
```

this will tell the compiler that the type of `result` is `{value: "a"}` and not `{value: string}`

Comment: Isn't the return type more like `{ value: 'a' }` instead of `Options` now? It's assignable, but `{ value: 'b' }` cannot happen with this declaration.

Comment: I guess he will do `{value: 'b'} as const` as well when he needs it. Type of `getOption` is still `Options` tho

Comment: @MikeS. the return type is `Options` - that's the annotation the function has. And it returns something structurally compatible to `Options`, this the typing is correct.