# Infer multiple possible types in passed array (spread operator)

Tags: typescript, types, type-inference, conditional-types

I'm looking for a way to infer type for **each and every spread argument** of my type function.

Let's say I have the two fields with the following definition.

```
type Field<T> = { value: T, name: string }

const field1 = { value: 12, name: 'age' }
const field2 = { value: 'foo', name: 'nickname' }
```

and I want to be able to pass these fields as my spread arguments to the following function, that would be called in a following fashion

```
useForm('registration', field1, field2)
```

So I tried using a [conditional type inferrence](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#type-inference-in-conditional-types) as per the official docs, which did solve the issue for the most part

```
type InferredFields<T> = T extends { value: infer V }[]
  ? Record<string, Field<V>>
  : never

const useForm = <T extends Field<unknown>[]>(name: string, ...args: T) => {
  const fields: InferredFields<T> = args.reduce(
    (res, field) => ({
      ...res,
      [field.name]: field.value,
    }),
    {} as InferredFields<T>,
  )
  return {
    name,
    fields
  }
}

const form = useForm('bar', field1, field2)
```

My only issue is, it cannot properly discriminate the union produced by the inferred value of the passed array generic based on which value we are using.

```
type FieldValue<T> = T extends { value: infer V } ? V : never

// This is an issue since the return type of form is
// { fields: Record<string, string | number> } 
// instead of the properly inferred value type
const v1: FieldValue<typeof field1> = form.fields['age'].value // error
const v2: FieldValue<typeof field2> = form.fields['nickname'].value // error
```

[image]

Any idea how can i properly map the value types for each `Field` type passed as an argument?

- [Link to the TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#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-TbkjQOl0ejwngxHgIoAAfJjkFjm2LYURx0oLCAkZBQct5gtQMDcSSQbiIEDD0UJdTOPMu3WyIhKGhuj2oUuT+lKNKVlgvDU1YymQx1Nke7eLIjafeHd3OI8uk8O89uDYrzBG9fACIJ70fZwRCAA)

Comment: Is [this](https://tsplay.dev/WGRKXm) what you want? There are various discrepancies with your example code. Why do you use `field1` and `field2` to index into `form.fields`? Shouldn't it be `age` or `nickname` because that's what the field names are? Why are you accessing `value` on the field? Shouldn't the field be its value already? Not the field itself?

Comment: This does not really make sense. Why are you trying to access `form.fields['field1']`. Why `'field1`? This is only the name of the variable but you are never passing this information to the function. Did you mean to write `form.fields['age']`?

Comment: @TobiasS @caTs Yes, sorry. That was just oversight on my part when changing my original code to minimal reproducible example. It should be `form.fields['age']` instead. Edited my original question

Comment: @SamuelHulla As @caTS [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73920034/infer-multiple-possible-types-in-passed-array-spread-operator#comment130520805_73920034), you must use a [const assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) (`as const`) because TS does not [infer](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html) literal types from object property values.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeScript struggling with simple type inference for string literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73456254/typescript-struggling-with-simple-type-inference-for-string-literal)

Comment: @jsejcksn How would a `as const` assertion map the types on a mapped object? It's not like I can just pass `as const` to the default `{}` object in `.reduce`? And I do not know the exact value types from the mapping function. I fail to see how this would apply because least to my knowledge `as const` would make sense if i only knew the exact object structure in advance, which is not the case in this question. Could you post an example of what you mean?

Comment: If you don't know the exact object structure in advance, then this is not possible...

Comment: @caTS i know the exact object structure, but i do not know the type of the `value` property in each and every passed `...args` parameters

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73920034/infer-multiple-possible-types-in-passed-array-spread-operator?noredirect=1#comment130522489_73920034) @SamuelHulla You can build a type using recursion and conditional inference like is being done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70499768/438273).

Comment: @jsejcksn Yup thanks a lot, I did not know type recursion is possible in typescript. That actually is super helpful, especially considering TS has no runtime on compile, so recursion is not that big of a deal. Still had some tinkering to do, but iltimately it was enough to guide me towards the correct answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, this is bit tricky because it requires a type recursion.

Essentially I created the following type:

```
export type FormFields<T extends readonly unknown[]> = T extends readonly [
  infer FieldType,
  ...infer Rest,
]
  ? FieldType extends { value: infer V }
    ? { [key: string]: Field<V> } & FormFields<Rest>
    : never
  : never
```

It's a bit difficult to explain on first glance and easier to comprehend if you use it, but I'll try my best.

Where we pass a generic `T` in a shape of `unknown[]`. We extract always the first value (type) `FieldType` of the array and the inferred rest parameter `Rest`.

We then match the object and infer it's value `V` in a form of another generic. Now we can finally shape our object that will be of type `Field<V>` where we are passing the value type `V` to our type `Field` from the question. Finally we intersect it `&` with a recurssive call to our type `FormFields` in a shape of `FormField<Rest>` where we pass the remaining arguments of the array, extracting their types in a *FIFO* style recursive algorhitm.

Now we can finally use the type in our `useForm` function.

```
const useForm = <T extends Array<Field<unknown>>>(
   name: string
   ...addedFields: T
) => addedFields.reduce(
 (fields, field) => ({
   ...fields,
   [field.name]: field,
 }),
 {} as FormFields<T>
) as FormFields<T>
```

Technically it's not ideal, because if you were to try to assign it to a constant, i.e.

```
const fields: FormFields<T>
```

then you would get a type error that `Field<unknown>` is not assignable to `FormFields<T>`, because of our constraint in the defined `useForm` which specifies `T` as `Array<Field<unknown>>`. that's because the `FormFields` type generic `T` must be instantiated to `unknown[]` other the inferred type would never match the constraint of `Field` and then on the other hand the `useForm` requires a constraint to `Array<Field<unknown>>` otherwise the user could just pass any array into the rest arguments. So it's kind of a compromised solution, but ultimately the final assertion with `as` counts as "good enough" for me as it maintains the desired object shape with all the required types.

Now you get correct types from the recursive infer:

```
form.fields['age'] // Field<12>
form.fields['nickname'] // Field<'foo'>

// bonus below (unnecessary for answer):

// if you need to convert Field<'foo'> to Field<string> for let's say
// an onChange handler, which cant have "as const" styled value
// for arguments, its just a matter of a simple helper
export type InferredToPrimitive<T> = T extends string
  ? string
  : T extends number
  ? number
  : T extends boolean
  ? boolean
  : T extends Record<string, unknown>
  ? Record<string, unknown>
  : T extends Array<unknown>
  ? Array<unknown>
  : T
```

Comment: Note: I'll wait a bit before accepting this answer, to see if anyone can come up with even a better solution.